# Placing an image at the bottom right corner

Tags: html, css

I need to place an image ... at the bottom right corner inside a div with background image.. the problem is that the image is placed without background of the div.

i have this... im usign boilerplate

```
 <style>
 #footer-container{
    background: url("img/footer_bg.gif") repeat;
    color: #ccc;
    padding:20px 0;
 }
 #footer-container footer{
    background: url("img/footer_bg.gif") repeat;
    color: #ccc;
    padding:20px 0;
 }
 .wrapper{
    width:1026px; /* 1140px - 10% for margins */
    margin:0 auto;

 }
 #resize{
    float:right;
 }
 </style>
 <div id="footer-container">
    <footer class="wrapper">

    <p class="contacto">
    <i>
    some text here....
    <a href="#">—Contact</a>
    </i>
    </p>

        <div id="contacts">
            <a href="#" class="twitter-link">twitter</a>
            <a href="#" class="dribble-link">dribble</a>
            <a href="#" class="rss-link">rss</a>
        </div>
        <div id="resize">
            <img src="img/resize.png"
            style="position:absolute;right:0px; top:bottom; z-index:2;">
        </div>  
    </footer>
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "the image is placed without background of the div"?

Comment: Have you saved the .png with transparency?

Comment: the image is a .png with transparency... I want the whole background of #footer-container, but the resize.png have nothing its just white the color of the body background. the image is placed fine the problem is the background image of #footer-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand the issue. But if you want the image to be absolutely positioned inside the div, then I'd add `position:relative;` to the div you want to anchor the image inside of.

Comment: that works fine. actually leave it in position: fixed; actually leave it in position: fixed as the site http://cssgrid.net/

Answer (score 0):

style="**float:right;** 
**margin-bottom:{whatever suits you};** position:absolute; right:0px; top:bottom; z-index:2;"

Comment: thanks..but I want the background of #footer-container, cover everything and the image of the corner appears without the background